# How to get dimensions of div with overflow hidden in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a large div set to 100% width and height of the window. It is scrollable with `overflow: hidden`. How can I find out the width of the entire inside of element? `$('#gallery').scrollWidth` returns Undefined and anything else give me the window width.

I understand that the window width is the "correct" dimensions of the div, but is there a way to get the dimensions of the contents that are scrollable inside?

Comment: Have you tried using `overflow: auto;` with a clearfix instead of `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: The design requires overflow to be hidden.

Comment: can you put the basic html here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a div on the inside of your current div and taking the dimensions of that?